# ASP.NET Bind() in DropDownList - String Value vs. Null

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, data-binding

I hope someone can answer this. I'm pulling my hair out!

I have a `DropDownList` with a default value of "" to catch NULLs from the database.
The "Value" field of the `DropDownList` is a `varchar`.
This works fine.
However, when SAVING the record, the value is persisted as an empty string in the database.
 Rebinding that record later throws an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`.
Any recommended solution?

 
I'm currently using the below binding method:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DestinationDropDownList" runat="server" 
   DataSourceID="CountryDataSource" DataTextField="Name" 
   DataValueField="CountryRegionCode" SelectedValue='<%#Bind("DestinationCountryCode")%>'
   AppendDataBoundItems="True">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Select..." Value=""></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Found the problem:** 
The Country value field in the database was a fixed length, so it was trying to bind to "   " (3 spaces), where the existing `ListItem` value was just "".
I changed the default ListItem value to "   " and now it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

The region could be you are binding the dropdown list on page load.

Bind it inside `if(!Page.IsPostback)` it should work

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
   //bin your dropdown here
}
```

### Edit

I don't know weather it is going to work or not but you can create a property like below

```
private string _myProperty;
public string MyProperty
{
    get { return _myProperty; }
    set
    {
        if (value == String.Empty)
        {
            _myProperty = null;
        }
        else
        {
            _myProperty = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The DropDownList is actually tied directly to a DataSource, so I'm not sure how that would work. Isn't that handled by the DataSource?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm not sure why it reads the NULL just fine, but re-saves it as an empty string. Then it can't read the empty string. :(

Comment: Currently trying to do something like this but I'm using Entity Framework so not exactly sure how I might do that.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I found the answer and replied above in case you are curious to see.